# php write string to socket

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to write a string to socket. The string I am trying to write is

SET 4 1

This is my function that writes to the socket

```
function write_to_socket($socket, $msg)
{
    $sock = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("socket_create() failed: reason: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    echo '<br>socket created<br>';

    socket_connect($sock, $socket) or die("socket_create() failed: reason: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    echo 'Connected to '.$socket.'<br><br>';


    $length = strlen($msg);

    while (true)
    {
        echo 'Going to write '.$msg.'<br>';
        $sent = socket_write($sock, $msg, $length);
        //echo 'Read '.socket_read($sock, $length).'<br>';
        if ($sent === FALSE)
        {
            echo "could not write<br>";
            break;
        }
        // Check if the entire message has been sent
        if ($sent < $length) {
            // If not sent the entire message.
            // Get the part of the message that has not yet been sented as message
            $msg = substr($msg, $sent);
            // Get the length of the not sented part
            $length -= $sent;
            echo $length." more characters need to be writte<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Finished writing<br>";
            break;
        }
    }
    echo 'Done writing '.$msg;

    socket_close($sock);
}
```

This function outputs

```
socket created
Connected to /tmp/cool_socket

Going to write SET 4 1
Finished writing
Done writing SET 4 1
```

The problem that I am having is that 4 1 gets written to socket but SET does not. I am listening to socket and printing any message that gets printed to it. So once I send `SET 4 1` to the socket, the socket program outputs 4 1. What exactly am I doing wrong and why doesn't SET get send?

The code where I am calling the function is this

```
$i = 1;
define("RESTART", " 4");
define("SOCKET_DIRECTORY", '/tmp/');
$msg = "SET".RESTART." ".($i);
write_to_socket(SOCKET_DIRECTORY.get_socket_name($i), $msg);
```

where get_socket_name($i) returns cool_socket every time regardless of what value I send it.

Thanks to anyone for their help.

Comment: Have you considered that it may be the listener at fault, and the string is being sent correctly? What does the code for the other side of the socket look like?

Comment: How are you listening to the socket on the receiving end?

Comment: The code on the other side is tested and is fine. Originally both codes were written in C++, I just want to port to php because I like php much more better than C++. And listener works well with the other program, so when the writing program( written in C++) sends SET 4 1, then SET 4 1 gets outputted on the listening end, but when php does it, only 4 1 appears.

Comment: Can you show the code where the `write_to_socket` function is being called. More specifically the string you are passing to it.

Comment: Have you tried writing another string in to the socket? Something longer, and different chars, for debugging purposes?

Comment: @MeLight thank you very much for this idea. I have spent the whole night yesterday writing bunch of different strings, and what I have noticed is that when I use AF_UNIX socket I had to write SET SET 4 1 Apparently it seems that SET is a keyword of some kind for that socket. When I did not include SET as a beginning word for the string then nothing was sent. Thanks to everyone for their help and guidance!

Comment: Very welcome, hope it works out :)

Comment: $msg = "SET".RESTART." ".($i); -> try $msg = sprintf("SET %d %d", RESTART, $i);